# Are pilots armed?

Tags: security, terrorism

Are pilots armed to defend themselves in event of a terrorist attack? It seems that in view of terrorist attacks and hijackings since 9/11 they would be.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Some pilots are armed, like casey says. Most, however, are not. And they have very little reason to:

1. After 9/11, a lot stricter security measures have been made on all airplanes to limit the access non-essential staff has to the cockpit. This includes measures like a reinforced locked door between the cabin and cockpit.
2. Because of the improved measures, terrorists these days are less inclined to use the plane as a weapon, choosing instead to use bombs in their shoes, underwear or carryon luggage to detonate the plane.
3. A gun on a plane can be dangerous, especially in the cockpit. it can hit vital instrumentation, damage the fuselage or a window, or cause friendly fire.
4. In the confined space of an airplane, some self-defense training is likely to be more useful than a gun. in addition to collateral damage, a gunshot can cause the passengers to panic. An assailant can also steal the gun, giving even more cause for concern.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Is the Mythbusters link broken?

Comment: Note that, as shown by [Mythbusters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fi1_1l7M8FA), putting a bullet through a plane window does a whole lot of nothing much at all.

Comment: @DavidRicherby indeed, the hole provided by the outflow valves is far bigger than a bullet hole.

Comment: Note that Mythbusters was debunking the "Explosive decompression" myth. Note also that this answer makes no mention of explosive decompression. You're tilting at windmills here. As seen on the show, shooting a window *does* still do significant damage to the window, damage which in the cockpit can obscure the pilot's visibility. I'd call that dangerous.

Comment: @JonathanVanMatre Sure, it causes damage and, sure, landing the plane without that damage would be safer than landing it with. However, the damage is by no means disastrous and you need to consider the baseline. If you're seriously considering firing a gun in the cockpit, the situation must be pretty seriously bad. If you manage to end that situation and the only cost to the aircraft is that you can't see through the whole of one of your windows, that probably means you've got yourself into a much safer place than you were in before you fired the gun.

Comment: I wasn't referring to explosive decompression. what I was referring to was that if a window loses a lot of structural integrity (say, after a bullet hole), the window might be damaged even further if there are harsh enough winds. Also, a gun is mainly useful at range, and I doubt a hijacker could get any decent ranged weapon on board a plane, so they will likely attack you at close range.

Comment: You also need to take into account that you're unlikely to be prepared for a hijacking. By the time you noticed something is wrong, processed that you are under attack and have readied your gun (stand up, reach down, remove from holster, remove safety, aim), your assailant has had time to stab you. If you don't need to ready your gun (just stand up and prepare to defend yourself), you gain a few precious seconds. I believe you don't have more than 2-3 square meters in a cockpit, which is too confined a space for using a gun effectively, one would assume.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Entirely valid point, and now you're giving OP the respect of addressing his argument directly. Look at the dialogue that ensues when you aim your lance at real dragons. ;-)

Comment: @JonathanVanMatre Thanks for the praise but, actually, my lance was true all along. The strawman was entirely yours: I never said anything about explosive decompression. The video could have been addressing a myth that shooting through a plane window would cause a plague of locusts and it wouldn't have altered my point: nothing much happens when a bullet goes through an aircraft window at altitude. (Also, it was more a small informational sign than a lance.)

Comment: Don't misunderstand me...said praise was in no way faint. This is a far more interesting angle on the topic: where is the balance between the potential risk to the plane and the potential risk of not confronting an attacker storming the cockpit? If you harm the plane you imperil everyone on it, but how likely is the plane to be harmed? If you fail to harm an attacker bent on destroying the plane, you imperil everyone on it, but what if the attacker's intent does not include immediate peril to those on the plane? I'd be very interested in knowing how a pilot makes those choices.

Comment: @JohannesPille Since 9/11, all hijackings involving intrusion into the cockpit have been with the aim of landing the plane somewhere else, not something terrorists usually do. I have not heard of a single hijacking aimed at using the craft as a weapon, only as leverage. Meanwhile, a number of plots involving bombs in carry-on luggage, shoes, underwear or other places have been intercepted and defused. A hijacking is still dangerous, but it happens less in commercial craft lately than attempts at bombing an aircraft. 9/11 is still an isolated incident, however horrible it was.

Comment: @Nate, I was not contending that at all. 9/11 most definitely was an isolated incident indeed. However, how often was a bomb in a shoe found or used, for instance? How many planes have been blown up in the past 10 years? How often has it been tried? *There is no threat.* Is what I'm saying.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs That's also a lot of hijackings before 9/11. Really, most hijackings have included "land the plane elsewhere" among their demands, where "elsewhere" is a place the hijackers think won't have them arrested. For that matter, hijackings like that can be done through the threat of explosives, so it's all mixed.

Comment: @JohannesPille Last 10 years: Wiki lists 6 attempts, 2 of which brought down their targets (and one of those had 2 planes attacked, so 3 planes brought down in the last 10 years). In the 90s, there was 1 successful bombing, which was a test run to a failed large-scale plot; in the 80s, there were 9 resulting in deaths.

Answer (score 21):

Some are -- in the US.  The TSA has a program called [Federal Flight Deck Officer (FFDO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Flight_Deck_Officer) that involves training from the US Federal Marshals.  The pilots who participate in this program are armed but will not display that status when in view of the public so you will normally be unable to identify them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with a gun is that if staff are the terrorists then everything becomes that much more dangerous.
In some cases such as FedEx hijacking, and other ones, the chance of the hijacking being an inside job is higher. Therefore it was much more easier to overpower one hijacker who wanted to assault crew physically, than it would be if he were carrying a gun.
Guns usually make things much much worse.

EDIT: Even if the pilot has a gun. It still gives opportunity for the hijacker to snatch the gun. Pilots are usually busy flying the plane rather than constantly inspecting who is behind them and having a gun on the ready. And if the flight is a long one and pilot retrieves into the bed to sleep then likelihood of having the gun snatched is even higher. And if you look at some hijackings, the hijacker usually has the jump on the victims, so him obtaining a gun would not be too difficult.

Comment: Yet if the pilot, who *is already in control of the aircraft* has a gun, it really doesn't make him much more able to hijack the plane, now does it? It would be a different matter if we were talking about stewards, and in that case I'd agree, but we're talking about *pilots* here

Comment: in case of the FedEx case, had the other crewmembers had guns to control the situation, the attempt would have been over a lot earlier. It was because the hijacker had an axe and the person trying to control him was unarmed that it took as long as it did.

Comment: For anyone that hasn't seen it, the Air Crash Investigation/Mayday episode on this flight is worth watching:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQcNxESf-Ho

Comment: @jwenting if pilots had a gun, then instead of him using an axe, he would have changed his plan to snatch pilot's gun rather than charge in with an axe. And then a desperate man with a gun will be more reckless in his shooting than pilots who would try not damaging the plane and plunging to their fiery death.