# Are US pilots permitted to carry & use their firearm in countries where guns are illegal?

Tags: security, eu, ffdo

On the question of [Are pilots armed?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2761/are-pilots-armed), one thing this made me think is: for the few that *are* armed, are they allowed to bring their weapon into, for example, the UK?

What is the procedure? Does the gun stay in the cockpit or does it need to be checked by security once on the ground?

Presuming a pilot had to fire a gun over EU airspace, is he breaking the law?

Comment: @casey Looks like it comes under [44921§b.3.J](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/49/44921)

Comment: Those laws can get amusing.  I don't know if it's still the law, but at least in the past it was required for private pilots to carry a gun in the airplane in Alaska.  Where I live, it's long been illegal to take a gun onto the airport property.  Not sure how one was supposed to fly from here to there.  :-)  Stop partway there and buy a gun???  :-)

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch yes, or there was a clause that allowed flights not originating within the state to fly without a gun on board (thus giving you time to buy one locally).

Answer (score 2):

Once you land you have to abide by the laws where you are. In the US federal laws (if there are any), when flying in US airspace.

Most US laws about airports and guns, only apply to the secured space. (Inside security), not the GA ramp or anyplace else.

Comment: Can you leave the gun in the plane in a country where it's illegal, or do you have to remove it before the flight?